# How to reduce the SSL Overhead in Python Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have created a code to **update real time data** into firebase using the **firebase_admin** sdk in python, but the **ssl overhead** made the total download size pretty large. is there anyway to reduce the ssl overhead and create a **persistent connection** with firebase **realtime database** using **python.**

```
#Import 
import xlrd
import sched, time

#scheduler
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

#Firebase admin
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db

cred = credentials.Certificate(r"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Pythons\Resource\AccountKey.json")

#Initilising Database
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL' : 'https://database.firebaseio.com/'
})

#Loop to run every second
def do_something(sc):
    print("Opening excel....")

    #Opening Document
    file_location=r"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\NIFTY 50 Fyers.xlsm"
    try:
        workbook=xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
        print("Opened")

        #Opening first sheet
        sheet=workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
        #Creating stockdictionary
        stockdata={}

        for i in range(1,50):
            stockdata[str(sheet.cell_value(i,0))]=sheet.cell_value(i,1)

        #Writing data into firebase database    
        db.reference("Live Data/N50 Stocks").update(stockdata)

        #Display Result
        print("Stock Data Updated")


        indicesdata={}
        for j in range(74,100):
            indicesdata[str(sheet.cell_value(j,0))]=sheet.cell_value(j,1)

        #Writing data into firebase database    
        db.reference("Live Data/Indices").update(indicesdata)

        #Display Result
        print("Indices Data Updated")

        #Opening second sheet
        sheet=workbook.sheet_by_index(1)

        optionsdata={}
        for k in range(2,41):
            optionsdata[str(sheet.cell_value(k,0))]=sheet.cell_value(k,2)

        #Writing data into firebase database    
        db.reference("Live Data/Options").update(optionsdata)

        #Display Result
        print("Option Data Updated")


        #All data finished
        print("____________")

    except Exception:
        print("*********Exception Occured**********")
        #Calling Loop Again
        #s.enter(1, 1, do_something, (sc,))
        pass

    #Calling Loop Again
    s.enter(1, 1, do_something, (sc,))

#Repeat
s.enter(1, 1, do_something, (s,))
s.run()
```

This connection should be persistent for 8 hours and firebase ssl overhead reducing method is pretty hard to digust, can anybody shorten this code to avoid the ssl overheads and make the data connection with firebase smooth and uses less data downloads.

Answer (score 0):

After few years of testing, I found the answer

`There is no way to reduce overhead` but we can `reduce the number of writes per second`

#### Solution

- Avoid too many writes per second
- Combine the data into a dictionary and update it in 5 min interval as 1 single request rather than 1 second updates
- If you want to update multiple child nodes, Try to do it with single request, rather than multiple single write request

### Bad Way

```py
data_list={1:{"Reliance":2500},2:{"LT":3500},3:{"Airtel":2500}}
print(data_list)

for key in data_list:
    data=data_list[key]
    stockdata=data.keys()
    stock_name=list(stockdata)[0]
    value=data[stock_name]
    
    print(list(stockdata)[0],":",value)
    
    update_db_everysecond(stockname,value)
```

#### Good way

```py
last_updated_time=now()
store_into_single_file={}

def store_it_in_bulk(stockname,value):
 if store_into_single_file
 store_into_single_file[timeinmill]={}

 if(last_updated_time-now()>5_minutes):
  Update_the_database()
  update last_updated_time
  store_into_single_file.clear
 else:
  store_into_single_file[timeinmill][stockname]=value


for key in data_list:
    stock_name=list(data_list[key].keys())[0]
    value=data_list[key][stock_name]

    print(list(stock_name,":",value)
    store_it_in_bulk(stock_name,value)
```